# Solr : How AND works (Psuedo Code)

Tags: solr

Well I am making a algorithm before which I have to understand how solr handle results when it has to do AND between them.

```
    So Consider a scenario 

    id      Country    City                    
     1     India       Bangalore
     2     America     New York
     3     France      Paris
     4     America     Los Angeles
```

Now suppose my query is country = America and city = Los Angeles ..
Now Will solr work like this ??

```
Take all Ids for country = America i.e Id (2 , 4)
Then take all Ids for City = Los Angeles i.e (4)
Then Find common in both result set i.e (4).
```

If it is the way to resolve AND , then isn't have high complexity. 
Even too much high if we have more ANDs .

Can any one tell clear my doubts.

EDIT : To show usecase which clearly depict my requirements.

```
 Id(unique)     returnMe             desc                       name         value
1              user1            all those living in usa        country         USA
2.             user2            all those like game            game            football
3.             user1            my hobbies are                 hobby           guitar
```

Now how can I get returnMe for following queries ??

```
 1. For all those users who live in usa AND hobby is  guitar.
 2. For all those users who live in usa OR game is football.

Answer for query first should be user1
Answer for query second should be user1 and user2
```

Thanks

Comment: Well...It all depends on your Schema (field types, analyzers/tokenizers and filters), on whether u use that in `fq=` or `q=` etc

Comment: Well Right , it depends on analyzer and tokenzier but all these things related to searching in "index" . I am concern about the algorithm after that for above example, after searching for country America I have list of Ids and for "city" too . Then we have to take common Ids. High complexity in extracting common Ids like in above case its (4) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr can do complex boolean operations across millions of docs really fast. Data goes into a reverse index of bitsets. I am no expert on it, but hope this illustration helps:

```
Documents [1,2,3,4]
country:america : "0101" (in bitset, 0 for absent and 1 for prese)
city:los angeles : "0001"
```

and so

```
country:america and city:los angeles => "0101" AND "0001" => "0001"
```

A 1,000,000 byte bitset can represent 1,000,000 documents (in worst case), and your computer can [access it](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html) in 19 microseconds from RAM and 2 milliseconds from disk. And CPUs are natural at doing boolean operations fast (the CPUs in our solr servers are hardly busy even at 100s of millions of documents).

And so Solr can do complex boolean operations across millions of docs really fast.

Comment: Ok Thanks .. Simple and clever way ... Well I am going to develop a custom request handler which will break queries on AND and then fetch documents for each query( on either side of AND) . After that I want all those docids which are present in all sets. How can I acheive this fast ?

Comment: How is`fq` (filter queries) and result grouping not enough for your requirements? Do you have a strong use case for that?

Comment: Well I have edited my question to depict my requirements. Can you suggest me how will you fetch documents using fq ..

Answer (score 1):

Bitsets might come into it in the case where a Filter is used: results of filters get cached in memory as bitsets for fast lookup.

But in the general case, what happens is that Lucene creates an iterator for each term; in your example there would be an iterator for America and another for Los Angeles.  Then Lucene iterates over these, and (in the case of AND) combines them by finding docids that exist in all the iterators.  This can be done very efficiently by: (1) iterating first over the iterator with the fewest total number of matches, and (2) skipping over any docids that are < the current matching docid.  Because docids are (usually) scored in order, this can be done.  In your example, the scorer for the Los Angeles term would be evaluated first because of its lower number of matching docs; the first match is "4".  Then the scorer for the America term would be evaluated, and told to skip ahead to "4" - a match is found, and then both iterators terminate.

The summary is: don't worry about this: the performance of this sort of thing is very good w/Lucene and Solr; it's the main reason they have become so widely accepted.

Comment: +1 for nice answer. Well I am concern about this because I am going to develop a custom request handler , which will break queries on AND and then fetch documents then take docids which are present in all iterators. All these process would be written by me . Thats why I am concern for performance . Any suggestion ?? I hope you get my problem

Comment: I suggest reading the code in BooleanQuery, and BooleanQuery2, and related classes and understanding that.  You will have to implement something similar.  The key idea is not to fetch all matching docs from one clause, and then all matching docs from the other clause: rather they should be streamed by a lazy (iterator-style) implementation to avoid considering unneeded documents.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey, Thanks Dude :) ... Well I have edited my question to specifically depiciting my requirements . Can you please look into it . Another thing Can you give me some reference to read about iterator-style implementation thing you have pointed out above. I have almost no idea about this :)