# Solr: How to break query on 'AND' and 'OR'?

Tags: solr

I am writing customize request handler and I have such a requirements that I have to break the query into multiple clauses.

Suppose I am getting query:

```
I live in America and love pizza or play cricket.
```

then I want to get  three clauses out of it.

```
1. I live in America
2. love pizza
3. play cricket.
```

Is there any way ?? 
Can I do it through BooleanQuery class ? I have doubt :)

Comment: Why are you writing you own request handler for that? Both the standard and dismax handler has support for boolean operators.

Comment: hey , no I am not writing request handler for just breaking query. It is the part of my requirements.

Comment: Hm, I think you're barking up the wrong tree here... I'd check out the existing components before starting to write code. I've made over 20 large Solr projects and I've basically never had to write code to plug in. Not that its hard or so, its just not necessary.

Comment: Calm down , If you have worked on 20 LARGE projects and didnt find it neccessary to write code .. then see my requirements at [My requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380924/solr-how-and-works-psuedo-code#comment23477046_16380924) . Try to figure out if you can .. good luck ; NOTE: read only "EDIT" part of my question

Comment: @MaxCharas : I am waiting for you answer

Comment: I've read the post you linked to and its all a bit unclear to me. As @Paige Cook is saying the best way to approach this specific problem is to preprocess the request making "I live in America and love pizza or play cricket" -> "I live in America" AND "love pizza" OR "play cricket". The thing I just want to make you aware of is that Solr more or less supports this kind of functionality inherently through its boolean operators (and filter queries) and of course its powerful relevance model (TF-IDF). Read through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf to see how Solr ranks up/down words.

Comment: Oh, and do check out http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax :)

Comment: Ok I will read .. But @Max problem is when i do "I live in America" AND "love Pizza" OR "play cricket" , Solr trying to match all these things per document (solr will list a documents only when document have "live in america" and "love pizza" or "play cricket"). May be you understood what i want to say

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29841/discussion-between-max-charas-and-voila)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be better to parse the sentence prior to passing it to Solr. That way you can look for the and/or keys and break it apart accordingly to produce the correct query. It has the added benefit of allowing you to perform this parsing in whatever programming/scripting language you would prefer or may have expertise with.

Comment: Ping @Paige, See if you want to add anything to the comments above :)